# Which countries count for the 90-day limit in the US Visa Waiver Program?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, countries

What are all the ineligible countries that do not restart the 90-day Visa Waiver into the USA?

Comment: To the close voters: The other question is closely related but does not ask (nor received an answer) about the countries included in the rule, only about the conditions under which it applies to Canada in particular.

Comment: +1, this is clearly a separate question not previously answered.

Answer (score 12):

A link on the [Visa Waiver Program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html) page (under "Trips to Canada, Mexico, or nearby Islands") points to the [Closed Loop Voyages](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/pleasure-boats-private-flyers/closed-loop-voyages-faq) page from the CBP. According to this page, the definitions of Contiguous Territories and Adjacent Islands is:

> Contiguous Territories are any country sharing a common boundary with the United States. Canada and Mexico are contiguous to the United States.
>
> Adjacent Islands as follows: Anguilla, Antigua, Aruba, Bahamas, Barbados, Barbuda, Bermuda, Bonaire, British Virgin Islands, Cayman Islands, Cuba, Curacao, Dominica, the Dominican Republic, Grenada, Guadeloupe, Haiti, Jamaica, Marie-Galantine, Martinique, Miquelon, Montserrat, Saba, Saint Barthelemy, Saint Christopher, Saint Eustatius, Saint Kitts-Nevis, Saint Lucia, Saint Maarten, Saint Martin, Saint Pierre, Saint Vincent and Grenadines, Trinidad and Tobago, Turks and Caicos Islands, and other British, French and Netherlands territory or possessions bordering on the Caribbean Sea.

Comment: I approved the edit so Stefan Birkner could get the reputation for it, but I think the text of the answer needs a little more tweaking to match the changes in the web pages.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Greg's answer. Adjacent islands are defined in [Immigration and Nationality Act §101](http://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1101&num=0&edition=prelim)

> The term “adjacent islands” includes Saint Pierre, Miquelon, Cuba, the Dominican Republic, Haiti, Bermuda, the Bahamas, Barbados, Jamaica, the Windward and Leeward Islands, Trinidad, Martinique, and other British, French, and Netherlands territory or possessions in or bordering on the Caribbean Sea.

Comment: I believe this is the correct definition of "adjacent islands" for this purpose, but one must be careful because there are other definitions of adjacent islands for other purposes within the scope of the INA (notably at [8 CFR 202.0](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/212.0)).