# Is there a list of countries that do not reset the "clock" for Canada visits?

Tags: visas, canada, north-america, saint-pierre-and-miquelon

Note: this is about Canada.

When travelling to the USA, you cannot [reset the 90-day counter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/which-countries-count-for-the-90-day-limit-in-the-us-visa-waiver-program) by going to Canada or Mexico, if you have entered the US using the Visa Waiver Program.

Is there similarly a rule for tourists (with or without a visa) in Canada, that prevents them from visiting a neighbouring country to reset the "clock" and get another 90/180 days of visits?

In particular, I am interested in the tiny islands of St-Pierre-et-Miquelon, which are a French territory. Could some Canadian visitor go there to reset the counter (obviously, assuming that this traveller is allowed to enter France)?

**EDIT** : I think I wrote my question in a confusing manner. What I have in mind is to figure the countries that 1. travellers with visa can visit without causing the visa to expire, 2. travellers without a visa who were allowed to visit Canada for X days, would not see this counter reset if they visit this country.

Let me know if this makes the question clearer, or if it is just confusing.

Comment: Wait, which counter? The 90 day tourist one? I actually thought just leaving Canada reset it - maybe not to USA...but..no?

Comment: @MarkMayo Yup, this one, at least I suppose it concerns these travellers that do not need a visa. I remember reading somewhere on a Canada government website that going to the USA does not reset it, but I cannot find it any more.

Comment: @pnuts thanks I guess that's the same countries that are considered not resetting this counter.

Comment: @pnuts, yeah multiple options, that's why I was clarifying :D

Comment: @pnuts. You should write an answer based on your comment. It effectively answers the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pnuts did give you the link in comments, but to expand further, from [cic.gc.ca](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=417&t=16):

> A single entry visa allows you to come to Canada only one time. Once you have left Canada, excluding travel to the United States and St. Pierre and Miquelon, you will need a new visa to travel back to and enter Canada.

and

> A multiple entry visa allows visitors to come and go from Canada for six months at a time, without having to reapply each time. It can be valid for up to 10 years, or one month before your passport expires, whichever is earlier. You must arrive in Canada on or before the expiry date on your visa.

Specifically to your question:

> If your visa is still valid and you are travelling **only and directly to the United States (including its Territories and Possessions) or St. Pierre and Miquelon**, you do not need a new visitor visa to return to Canada.

So US, St. Pierre and Miquelon are fine - no impact on your visa. All other countries either require a new visa (if you are on single visit) or have no impact (if you are on a multiple entry visa).

Note that since February 2014, Canada does not seem to issue single-entry visa any more, so visiting any country should not joepardize the duration you are allowed to stay in Canada:

> Starting on February 6, 2014 (00:01 EST), all visa applicants will automatically be considered for a multiple entry visa.

Comment: Well in fact my reading of this document is that travellers with single-entry visa to Canada could visit the US without their visa expiring, so it does not "reset" the time allowed to visit. In opposition, visiting e.g. Mexico would "reset" the visa, i.e. the traveller would have to get a new visa. See my edit, I think it is my question which is confusing in the first place.

Comment: Hopefully my update covers that, Vince?

Comment: Rory, I interpret that last quote as "you don't have to explicitly apply for a multi-entry visa" but you could still get a single entry visa.

Comment: @mkennedy I think it is more "you might be granted a multiple-entry visa even if you don't ask or want it", but I suppose they still keep the possibility to give some single-entry visa. Their wording is not clear to me.

Comment: "all applicants will automatically be considered for a multiple entry visa" does not mean that all visas issued will be multiple entry visas.