# Can Europeans reset their "time in Canada" clock by visiting the US?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, visa-runs, swiss-citizens

If a Swiss citizen comes to Canada and stays for 6 months, can they travel to USA for example, for a short period of time, and then return to Canada for another 6 months?  How long must they stay out of Canada before returning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of countries that do not reset the time limit for Canada visits?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44462/is-there-a-list-of-countries-that-do-not-reset-the-time-limit-for-canada-visits)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that; in fact opposite

Comment: [This page from Immigration Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=473&top=4) would imply that the answer is No, since a visit to the US does not reset a single-entry visa, and so is unlikely to reset the clock for any particular visit.

Comment: @CGCampbell Not the opposite at all, but the same question I think.

Comment: For me not a dupe of the linked question. It is closely related to and maybe a dupe of question 2 after the edit in that question, but the only (and accepted) answer only deals with the visa situation and not the passport situation. A good example of why one question at a time is a good idea.

Comment: Ahh darnit, I misread the dupe, thinking it was a standard US centric one, you're right, it's also about reset the Canadian 'clock' as well

Answer (score 6):

In the [Canadian law](http://www.canlii.org/en/ca/laws/regu/sor-2002-227/latest/sor-2002-227.html#sec183_smooth) your authorized period of stay in Canada begins on the date you enter the country and ends at the earlier of the date you were permitted to stay until or the date you leave Canada. A new entry into Canada requires you to be authorized for a new period of stay; there are no exceptions based on the country you travel to when you leave. Note that this technically applies even to those with single entry visas, who are instead granted a visa exemption for their subsequent entries within their originally granted period of stay if the travel was to the US or St Pierre et Miquelon (travel to those places is exceptional only in this context, it is mentioned no where else in the law).

Whether you will be authorized for a 6 month stay on a subsequent (or any) entry is a different issue. The default in the law is 6 months but the border officer has the discretion to fix your stay at time requested or to that for which you have the means to support yourself, or even to refuse your entry or place additional conditions on your stay if they suspect the purpose of your visit is inappropriate.

What period of stay they actually give you on a reentry is hence more a matter of policy than of law, and since the CBSA is quite opaque about their policies the only way to guess at that is for people to report what happened to them. My only data point is entirely ambiguous. Friends I took on a day trip across the land border did not have a new stamp put in their passports on reentry, nor did the officer look for the previous stamp, but they had 5.5 months left from the previous entry and told him they were only staying 2 weeks more so the issue wasn't very important. I have no idea whether the CBSA record was left with the original 5.5 month authorized date or gave them a new 6 months that he was too busy or lazy to stamp into the passport.

In any case, in the law you are always free to request a new 6 month stay when entering Canada as a visitor no matter where you travelled to. Whether they will grant it or not is at their discretion. You are also free to apply to [extend your stay while inside Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend-stay.asp), which has the advantage that you'll automatically get to stay until they tell you "no".

Comment: +1 thanks for this detailed answer. I'm still a little skeptical on the visa exemption clause, which doesn't explicitly mention single-entry visas, and so as far as I could tell could be interpreted as saying "visits to the US and St. P&M don't count as having left for the purposes of your current visa".  But the general point about the policy vs. law is absolutely correct.