# Do Canadian entry stamps normally show a length of stay or "admitted until" date?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

Various questions about visiting Canada talk about periods of authorised entry being granted by the border Guard (e.g. [Can Europeans reset their "time in Canada" clock by visiting the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69145/can-europeans-reset-their-time-in-canada-clock-by-visiting-the-us?noredirect=1&lq=1) ) and imply that these are indicated in the passport stamp.

However when I visited Canada about a year ago as a British Citizen the stamp in my passport only showed that the stamp was issued by the Canadian border services agency (in both English and French) the entry date, a large number (which I assume was the number of the border officer) "LBPIA" (which seems to be a reference to where the stamp was issued) and possiblly some tiny text under the date (looks like it may be "canada" repeated but blurred by bad stamping), no mention about periods of authorised stay.

How do canadian entry stamps work? is it normal for them to only show the date of entry? Does the lack of any indication of a period of entry mean I was authorised for the full 6 months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the lack of any indication of a period of entry mean I was authorised for the full 6 months?

Exactly so! If given less, the exit date was written.

I say "was" because Canada doesn't stamp passports anymore.

Comment: +1, no more Canadian passport stamps, so the question is moot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that what it means. You can stay in Canada for 6 months. That is based on my personal experience.

You are allowed to enter Canada as a visitor for 6 months. If the officer authorizes a stay of less than six months, they will indicate in your passport the date by which you must leave Canada.

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1016&top=16

If you want to stay longer than your authorized stay, you should apply for an extension at least 30 days before the authorized end of your stay.

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend-stay.asp