# Resetting ESTA by flying to Dominican Republic

Tags: esta

I read a lot here about resetting ESTA by going outside of US and then returning, but I still want to make sure I get it right. My 90 days will be over in October. I am planning to travel to Dominican Republic in September and then in October enter the US again.

Will it reset my ESTA for another 90 days?

One of my friends did so and he says it works, but I keep reading about an "adjacent islands zone" and am a bit worried.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does it mean that there is no rule or law which says that they do not stamp passports when travelling from nearby or "adjacent islands zone"? and only ICE officer decides either to let you in or not?

Comment: I decided to do a quick answer anyway. Hopefully I've not completely borked it up, as I don't have a lot of time at the moment to triple check.

Comment: I think that has the full answer you need; unfortunately the answer is "no".  Though I'll note that, as CGCampbell notes, the actual language on the state department website (As opposed to on various embassy sites) is more vague, so it's _possible_ an immgration officer could rule otherwise, but I wouldn't bet on it.  Perhaps if you are a resident or citizen of the Dominican Republic this could be different, though (I don't see how they can complain about you going home).

Comment: Also possibly useful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/which-countries-count-for-the-90-day-limit-in-the-us-visa-waiver-program

Comment: I think this post should be used as the answer, and the other marked as a duplicate, because the other one cites a foreign government website and this one cites US law *AND* the link in the other post is broken.

Comment: @CGCampbell Feel free to repost the very same quote to the original question

Answer (score 9):

The term "adjacent islands" is defined for the purpose of immigration law at 8 USC 1101(b)(5):

> The term “adjacent islands” includes Saint Pierre, Miquelon, Cuba, the Dominican Republic, Haiti, Bermuda, the Bahamas, Barbados, Jamaica, the Windward and Leeward Islands, Trinidad, Martinique, and other British, French, and Netherlands territory or possessions in or bordering on the Caribbean Sea.

Source: https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101

Traveling to the Dominican Republic therefore will not reset your VWP clock.